# How to append the values inside the list values in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
y = "1 2 3 ; 4 5 6;"
m = [x.strip().split(" ") for x in y.split(";") if len(x.strip()) > 0]
m
>> [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
result = {'x':[],'y':[], 'z':[]}
for i in m:
    result['x'] = i[0]
    result['y'] = i[1]
    result['z'] = i[2]

result
```

My out >> {'x': '4', 'y': '5', 'z': '6'}

My Expected out
     `{'x':[1,4],'y':[2,5], 'z':[3,6]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach using `dict` with `zip`.

```
d = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
result = ['x','y', 'z']
print(dict(zip(result, zip(*d))))
# or
print({k: list(v) for k, v in zip(result, zip(*d))})
```

**Output:**

```
{'x': ('1', '4'), 'y': ('2', '5'), 'z': ('3', '6')}
#
{'x': ['1', '4'], 'y': ['2', '5'], 'z': ['3', '6']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use te append built in method for lists

```
for i in m:
    result['x'].append(i[0])
    result['y'].append(i[1])
    result['z'].append(i[2])
```

You could also use the zip method to remove the for loop like this:

```
zipped_lists = list(zip(*[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]))

result['x'] = list(zipped_lists[0])
result['y'] = list(zipped_lists[0])
result['z'] = list(zipped_lists[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
y = "1 2 3 ; 4 5 6;"
m = [x.strip().split(" ") for x in y.split(";") if len(x.strip()) > 0]
m
>> [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
result = {'x':[],'y':[], 'z':[]}
for i in m:
    result['x'].append(i[0])
    result['y'].append(i[1])
    result['z'].append(i[2])

result
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the list not appending to it.

```py
y = "1 2 3 ; 4 5 6;"
m = [x.strip().split(" ") for x in y.split(";") if len(x.strip()) > 0]
m
>> [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
result = {'x':[],'y':[], 'z':[]}
for i in m:
    result['x'].append(i[0])
    result['y'].append(i[1])
    result['z'].append(i[2])

result
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are utilizing a dictionary that contains lists for each value, you need to work with the lists with the function `append`:

```
y = "1 2 3 ; 4 5 6;"
m = [x.strip().split(" ") for x in y.split(";") if len(x.strip()) > 0]
result = {'x':[],'y':[], 'z':[]}
for i in range(len(m)):
    result['x'].append(m[i][0])
    result['y'].append(m[i][1])
    result['z'].append(m[i][2])
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'x': ['1', '4'], 'y': ['2', '5'], 'z': ['3', '6']}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll add the defaultdict approach:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for i in m:
    result['x'].append(i[0])
    result['y'].append(i[1])
    result['z'].append(i[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
result_keys  = ('x', 'y', 'z')

result = {}
for m1, m2, key in zip(*m, result_keys):
    result[key] = [int(m1), int(m2)]


print(result)
```

output:

```
{'x': [1, 4], 'y': [2, 5], 'z': [3, 6]}
```